# Is there any way to re-write this question so it doesn't get closed as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I realized when I posted the question "[getting started as a web developer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27466/getting-started-as-a-web-developer)" that it was rather open-ended, but I still believe it is an important question. I spent quite a bit of time searching google and Amazon to try to find an authoritative discussion on the subject prior to posting, but what I really want is some seasoned professionals' advice on the 5-7 most important technologies for web-development. That's a general question, I know; but before I plunk down a couple hundred dollars at Amazon, and invest several weeks or months studying and reading about a given language, I want to make sure that it is not generally considered "obsolete" or whatever.

For those of you who have been immersed in web development for years, I'm sure this is a elementary question. But for those of us just getting started, it is pretty huge.

Is there any way to re-word this question, change the focus, or tighten it up to keep it from being closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of question isn't a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q/A format - that doesn't mean that it's a bad question, it's just not a good fit for the "practical, answerable questions" requirement (because it will undoubtedly turn into a discussion with competing opinions).

I'd recommend that you inquire in [Programmers chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers) or [StackOverflow chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms) (open-ended questions which solicit opinion versus fact are a better fit for for chat).

Comment: While I understand the policy, I must say that I fundamentally disagree with it. People come to StackExchange sites not only for simple answers to precise questions but also for expert opinions. Where else can practitioners solicit input on specific (if open-ended) questions from seasoned veterans of the field? I know my lone voice isn't going to make a dent in the policy, but I just needed to voice my dissent.

Comment: I will go ahead and accept your answer, not because I agree with it, but because I know it is the "correct" one. I guess I didn't really expect anything different.

Comment: The trouble with expert opinions is that there are so many of them, and they can vary so widely, and contradict each other. There is a site called webmasterworld which may welcome that type of question.

Comment: You're right @kmote, to a point. Stack Exchange is a knowledge base where non-experts can ask experts for knowledge in their field. Unforunately, the FAQ explicitly state what questions shouldn't be answered here - which are set up at the time of creation of the site and edited as time goes on.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask Please refer to the FAQ, and if you STILL disagree then we can debate about it.